# conexão persistente MysqlDb python

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Pelo fato de ter que ficar abrindo e fechando conexão com banco de dados o consumo de memoria sobe?
Gostaria de saber se eu utilizar uma conexão aberta sempre, terei vantagem de diminuir o consumo de memoria.

```
import MySQLdb

dblocal = MySQLdb.connect("host",
                        "user",
                        "password", 
                        "db")

cursor = dblocal.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ("tabela")
recordsdblocal = cursor.fetchall()
```

se for possível e viável como posso fazer isso?

[image: UTILIZANDO UM ORANGE PI ZERO 256MB:]

Comment: Por que o consumo subiria de ficar abrindo e fechando a conexão? Testou das duas maneiras para ver a diferença? Não que precise, mas se pudesse postar alguns números para embasar a questão, e talvez explicasse qual foi a dificuldade em manter a conexão aberta, seria mais produtivo para atrair respostas que foquem no núcleo do problema real que está tendo.

Comment: O grande problema é que não sei trabalhar com a conexão sempre aberta. Poderia me mostrar como faço isso para trabalhar analisar a diferença.

Comment: Basicamente seria só não fechar. Abre com connect no começo 1x só e guarde em dblocal como já fez no começo, depois usa sempre a mesma variável.dblocal em todos os cursores. Libere só cada cursor depois do uso (ou veja na documentação se tem como reaproveitar o cursor também - de qq forma tem que liberar os resultados que não precisa mais)

Comment: Dei uma olhada na documentação. não vi como aproveitar um cursor.

Comment: Acho que só de liberar cada cursor explicitamente de alguma forma já ajuda. De qq forma, vamos aguardar alguém que tenha prática com MySQLdb para dar exemplos mais concretos. O ponto central aqui é reaproveitar o connect.

Comment: Tetando Trabalhar assim.
Amigo já ajudou muito. muito obrigado
Esperando a resposta de outros colegas.

Comment: Já deu uma pesquisa sobre *connection pooling* com python? http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/db_pool.html

Comment: Não. agora que você falou vou dar uma olhada. Vlw